# Show $ \frac{n+1}{4n^2 + 3} $ is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

**Problem**: Show $ \frac{n+1}{4n^2 + 3} $  is a Cauchy sequence **( Using Cauchy Criterion only )**.
**Answer**:
We'll show $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}. a_{n+1} < a_n  $
[image]

So given $ \epsilon >0 $ we'll chose $ N_{\epsilon} = \lceil \frac{1}{2\epsilon} \rceil $ and then we indeed showed that the given sequence is Cauchy sequence.

**My question:** When I attempted myself, naively I tried by deriving something useful and easy to see from  $ a_{n+k} - a_{n} $ and then go ahead writing the proof more formally. But I got stuck in the middle because I'd get to an expression which is ugly and monstrous and it got me stuck. After looking at the answer, I wouldn't have thought to do as they did.
So I want to ask, how would you show the sequence is Cauchy sequence? Is there better alternative to the one purposed in the answer above?

Comment: My approach would have been to simplify the sequence, then use the simplified versions to estimate the values for $N_\varepsilon$. For example, we have $\frac{1}{8n}<a_n<\frac{1}{2n}$ by making some trivial estimates (like $3<4n^2$ and $1<n$). The simplified forms are much easier to work with.